# What is the most efficient way to automatically create a home folder for a user in Windows 2012 Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

i am looking for a more efficient way to automate home folder creations for our users instead of using active directory and right clicking and selecting properties  on the user and manually entering it every time under the "profile Tab".  is there a way using a GPO or do i have to create a powershell script, or is there some type of built in tool on windows server 2012 R2. I would like to Avoid powershell scripting if possible.

Answer (score 0):

GPO with wildcard redirect.

Check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786749%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which is titled "Configuring Folder Redirection".

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e999e32f-aaf4-4b8b-86e8-a5a2edde3dbb/group-policy-folder-redirection-using-username-variable

explains how you can embedd the username in the GPO so every user gets a separate path. Happens thre is a %username% variable available.